# Using Jquery to remove/add border on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there's several other threads with similar questions answered although I believe my question is slightly different.

Within my navigation the page you are currently on has a bottom border on the nav link. I'm trying to use Jquery to make it so that when you hover over any of the other links all borders are removed except for a new border on the hovered link. So within the example in JSFiddle when I hover over "About" the underline on "Home" would be replaced with an underline on "About" and then returned to "Home" when the mouseleaves.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ucmq/

Anybody have any suggestions? All help greatly appreciated!

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navigation a").hover(
                        function() {           $(this).removeClass("hoverEffectSelect"); }

            function() { $(this).addClass(".hoverEffect"); },
            function() { $(this).removeClass(".hoverEffect"); }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $home = $(".navigation a.hoverEffectSelect");
    $(".navigation a").hover(function () {
        $home.removeClass("hoverEffectSelect");
        $(this).addClass("hoverEffectSelect");
    },function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hoverEffectSelect");
        $home.addClass("hoverEffectSelect");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NVsM8/)

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Makes sense now :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery necessary: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ucmq/5/)

The idea is to apply the border-bottom to the active element *and* to the hovered one, but when the entire navigation is hovered over it should hide the border from the active element.

HTML:

```
<div class="headingTop">
    <div class="navigation">
        <a  class="hoverEffect active" href=".html">HOME</a>
        <a  class="hoverEffect" href=".html">ABOUT</a>
        <a  class="hoverEffect" href=".html">PROJECTS</a>
        <a  class="hoverEffect" href="r.html">CONTACT</a>
    </div><!-- DIV navigation -->
</div><!-- DIV headingTop -->
```

CSS:

```
.navigation a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Alef', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}

.hoverEffect {
    transition: border-bottom 300ms linear;
}
.navigation:hover>.active {
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}
.hoverEffect.active, .navigation>.hoverEffect:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EBCD37;
}
```

Comment: Wow, interesting. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3482096 You're welcome! I like pure-CSS solutions because they are orders of magnitude more efficient than any JavaScript solution, never mind jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".navigation a").hover(function() {
$(".navigation a").css('border-width', '0');
$(this).css('border', '3px solid black'); 
});
```

In this case you will remove the borders first, then set it as you want.

Comment: Almost perfect! The only thing it doesn't do is return the original underline to the "home" link... hmmm let me think

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = $('a.hoverEffectSelect').index();
    $(".navigation a").hover(function () {
        $(".navigation a").removeClass("hoverEffectSelect");
        $(this).addClass("hoverEffect");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hoverEffect");
        $('.navigation a').eq(index).addClass('hoverEffectSelect');
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ucmq/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var olda = $('.navigation a.hoverEffectSelect').index();
                $(".navigation a").hover(function (olda) {
                    $('.navigation a').removeClass("hoverEffectSelect");
                    $(this).addClass("hoverEffect");
                }, function () {
                    $('.navigation a:eq(' + olda + ')').addClass("hoverEffectSelect");
                });

            });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ucmq/6/)